# Queryset mocking

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test my below code, can someone help me with mocking `RecordStatus` & `Record`?

```
active_records = RecordStatus.objects.filter(report=report).filter(status=1)

inactive_records = Record.object.filter(pk__in=set(RecordStatus.objects.filter(report=report).filter(status=0).values_list('record_id', flat=True)))
```

Comment: Can you put your code into correct markdown pls.

Comment: You just gave a very part of code to us, but it look like you could need some more understanding of how QuerySets in Django work. In the code above you are using typical SQL patterns to solve your problem instead of taking advantage of the ORM features. Unluckily it's not possible to give detailed advise without knowing your models.

Comment: Is there a way I can change list to queryset?